# Error sending multiple records by API Rest to Salesforce

Tags: .net, rest, oauth, salesforce

When I try to send multiple records (h2) at once in the same JSON to Salesforce with a REST API, I get this error:

> "JSON deserialization failed on token 'null' and has left off in the middle of parsing a row. Will go to end of row to begin parsing the next row"

When I send h1, I have not a problem

Below is my method of sending data:

```
[HttpPost]
public static void PostDatasToSalesforce()
{
    string h1 = "{\"Titre_de_l_avis__c\":\"Test 1\",\"Account__c\":\"0015t00000nG9HlAAK\",\"Payant__c\":\"Oui\",\"Departement_principal__c\":\"92\"}";

    string h2 = "[{\"Titre_de_l_avis__c\":\"F1\",\"Account__c\":\"0015t00000nG9HlAAK\",\"Payant__c\":\"Oui\"}," +
                 "{\"Titre_de_l_avis__c\":\"F2\",\"Account__c\":\"0015t00000nG9HlAAK\",\"Payant__c\":\"Oui\"}]"

   using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", access_token);
        var dataJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(h2);
        var sendedData = new StringContent(dataJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var responseResult = httpClient.PostAsync(urlTest, sendedData).Result;
        var response = responseResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```